# android copy file to one with other name

Tags: java, android, rename, file-rename, internal-storage

For example I have 4 bitmaps in a folder in my internal storage:
right0, right1, right2, right3

And a ArrayList with the 4 uris of the Bitmaps:
uri0, uri1, uri2, uri3

Now i want to remove uri1/right1. That isn't that hard but I also want that uri2/right2 are renamed to uri1/right1 and uri3/right3 are renamed to uri2/right2.
So I want that there is always the order 0123...

I tried it with:

```
rightFolder= getDir("rightFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


for(int i = counter + 1; i <= uriList.size(); i++){//counter is 1 if i want to remove right1
    File tempFile = new File (rightFolder, ""+i);
    File newFile = new File (rightFolder, ""+(i-1));
    tempFile.renameTo(newFile); 
}
```

With this I tried to rename the files. And after that I removed the last uri in the list:

```
uriList.remove(uriList.size()-1);
```

But that didn't work. After debugging I've seen that the renameTo() method doesn't work. tempFile has the same name as before.
My idea was now that I copy right2 in the folder but than with the name right1 and then delete right2. But I don't know how to copy files in internal storage.

How can I fix this. Or does anyone have another idea to solve this problem?

Comment: It does not make sense to delete the last one in the list. You posted unreadable code as for instance we don't know rightFolder . And you do not want to copy but rename so the subject of your post is confusing.

Comment: added what rightFolder is.
I delete the last one because the order always stays 0,1,2, so I thought I don't have to delete one in the middle but the last.

Comment: ???? You wanted to delete the second one you said.  right1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete file and after that rename all other files. Maybe you can't rename because you have a file with the name that have already exist.